# Can you speak hypothetically without conditionals

Tags: word-choice, conditionals

In English, we often use "would" to directly make the sentence hypothetical, but how would you do this in Japanese? I only know how to use conditionals for this, but It doesn't give me the same feeling...

For example:

> You would make a good actor.
>
> 役者になったら、上手と思う。
>
> (If you were to become an actor, you would be good at it.)

Example 2:

> This sort of thing would be popular in Canada.
>
> カナダにあったら、こんな奴は人気だ。 (If this was in Canada, it would be popular.)

Can you see what I mean? I can't get the same meaning from Japanese...

How would I go about expressing these example sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using one of the forms だろう or でしょう would convey the idea that you want.

> You would make a good actor
>   上手な役者になるでしょう。

and

> This sort of thing would be popular in Canada.
>   こんなやつはカナダに人気でしょう。

Comment: The latter sentence should be …カナダ で（は）人気でしょう.  Here, で is essential and は is desirous.

Answer (score 1):

> In english we often use "would" to directly make the sentence hypothetical, but how would you do this in Japanese?
>
> You would make a good actor. 役者になったら、上手と思う (If you were to become an actor, you would be good at it)
> This sort of thing would be popular in Canada. カナダにあったら、こんな奴は人気だ (If this was in Canada, it is popular)
>
> I can't get the same meaning from Japanese...

**For the conclusion clause:** だろう／でしょう adds the sense of *assumption*. I find these are closer to English 'will' (でしょう is polite). These can be used in the *conclusion* clause but not a grammar requirement. For the uncertainty of 'would', we say かもしれない.

**For the premise clause:** When we especially have a need to say it's *hypothesis* ***contradicts an actual fact***, we do that by adding some expressions. For example,

> **もし万一**、役者になる（ような）ことが **あったとしたら**／**あるとしたら**、いい役者に**なる**と思うよ。

The above sentence means that it's very rare case but still possible. Here, なる for the future. Both **あった and ある works for the future** in the premise clause.

> **もし万一**、役者になる（ような）ことが **あったとしたら**、いい役者に**なった**／**なってた**と思うよ。

This is for the past. So, it's something about **no longer possible.**

*Cf:* In Japanese, we use the helping verb た not only to express the past but also the sense of completion in any tense. Not like English has the past tense form and the perfect form separately.